# Spark (shell), Cassandra : Hello, World?

Tags: installation, cassandra, apache-spark

How do you get a basic Hello, world! example running in Spark with Cassandra? So far, we've found this helpful answer:

[How to load Spark Cassandra Connector in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837436/how-to-load-spark-cassandra-connector-in-the-shell)

Which works perfectly!

Then we attempt to follow to documentation and the getting started example:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md

It says to do this:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo { session =>
  session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE test2 WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 }")
  session.execute("CREATE TABLE test2.words (word text PRIMARY KEY, count int)")
}
```

But it says we don't have `com.datastax.spark.connector.cql`?
Btw, we got the Spark connector from here:

[Maven Central Repository (spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11)](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark%20cassandra)

So how do you get to the point where you can create a keyspace, a table and insert rows after you have Spark and Cassandra running locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar you downloaded only has the Java api so it won't work with the Scala Spark Shell. I recommend you follow the instructions on the Spark Cassandra Connector page.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/13_spark_shell.md

These instructions will have you build the full assembly jar with all the dependencies and add it to the Spark Shell classpath using --jars.

Comment: Thanks, looks useful. Checking into this right now.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Currently unable to clone using their instruction:
Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Your advice worked out wonders. For some reason it didn't let me clone from that url so we cloned from github and it's running now!