# spark-shell dependencies, translate from sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt

While checking how to use the cassandra connection, the documentation instructs to add this to the sbt file:

```
"libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M1"
```

In general, is there an obvious, straight forward logic to translate this into the corresponding:

```
spark-shell --packages "field1":"field2"
```

I've tried:

```
spark-shell --packages "com.datastax.spark":"spark-cassandra-connector"
```

and a few other things but that doesn't work.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837436/how-to-load-spark-cassandra-connector-in-the-shell

Comment: yeah, saw that. It solves the issue of having the Cassandra connector on the shell, but I'm more interested in the general case, whether there is a logic there somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is `--packages "groupId:artifactId:version"`. If you have multiple packages, you can comma separate them. 
`--packages "groupId1:artifactId1:version1, groupId2:artifactId2:version2"`

In sbt

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.6.0-M1"
)
```

and

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M1"
)
```

are identical.
In case you use `%%` syntax (after the groupId) in sbt, it automatically picks up the artifact for your scala version.  So using scala 2.10 it changes your spark-cassandra-connector to spark-cassandra-connector_2.10. Not sure this feature is there when using spark-shell, so you might need to ask for the scala2_10 version of your artifact explicitly like this: `--packages "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0-M1"`

Answer (score 3):

Version should be specified.

`spark-shell --packages "com.datastax.spark":"spark-cassandra-connector_2.11":"2.0.0-M3"`

You can find version information from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspark-cassandra-connector .

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions as posted on the [Spark Packages Website](http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

To use the Spark-Shell

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10

There are also instructions for a variety of build systems

SBT

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M1-s_2.11"
```

And Maven

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- list of dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>datastax</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-M1-s_2.11</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <!-- list of other repositories -->
  <repository>
    <id>SparkPackagesRepo</id>
    <url>http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```